# on the extension module of a pair (some module, a finite free module)

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$ an $A$-module that admits a projective resolution. According to my understanding it is true that $\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,A^n) \cong \underbrace{\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,A) \times \cdots \times \operatorname{Ext}^i(M,A)}_{n}$. I proved this by applying the definition of the extension functor directly to the pair $(M,A^n)$. Is there some other quicker or more elegant way to prove this?

Comment: Well, $\mathrm{Ext}^i(M, -)$ is an additive functor, and additive functors preserve biproducts (i.e. finite direct sums/products).

Comment: Ok, that sounds along the lines of what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{Ext}^*(M,-)$ is the right derived functor of $\mathrm{Hom}(M,-)$. The right derived functor of an additive functor between abelian categories is additive. There are several ways how you can see this. For example, just use that the direct sum of two injective resolutions of $N$ resp. $N'$ is an injective resolution of $N \oplus N'$, etc.